# How well supported is the HTTP Upgrade mechanism?

Tags: http, ssl

I have been studying the Upgrade header field in HTTP 1.1 (RFC 2817) and happened to read the wikipedia entry for HTTP.  That article has the following statement:

> "Browser support for the Upgrade header is, however, nearly non-existent, so HTTPS is still the dominant method of establishing a secure HTTP connection."

I was hoping to implement my web service so that it relied on the Upgrade header field in order to avoid having to listen on two sockets (one for HTTP and the other for HTTPS).  This statement, which I have not been able to verify any other place, makes me somewhat nervous about doing so.  Is the above statement in wikipedia anywhere near correct or is it a gross generalisation?

Comment: It's normal to use port 80 for http and port 443 for https - why do you want to avoid listening on two ports?

Comment: ^ as thejh says, and furthermore, you _could_ use both SSL & non-SSL on the same port, but that's even worse IMHO.

Comment: RFC 2817 is designed to do exactly what Wrikken says and has an introduction which justifies the reasons for doing so.  I'm not sure why you say that it is "worse".

Comment: He wants to say that SSL and non-SSL on the same port is worse than HTTP Upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was researching this for that Wikipedia page actually and came across this question. I've looked around and here's the browser support situation as near as I can tell:

- Chromium supports the Upgrade header as indicated by, for instance, [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123862).
- Firefox does not support "Upgrade: TLS" despite [an open bug from 2005](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276813), last comment from 2010. My guess is they won't be adding it anytime soon.
- Internet Explorer 10+ probably does, given [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh969243.aspx) that describes using Upgrade to connect to a websocket server. [This commit message](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/pull/52) also implies IE 10 supports "Upgrade: websocket".
- Safari 6+ supports Upgrade (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nginxpushstream/GpXxpNF197A)).

For all of the supported browsers, I only found examples of "Upgrade: websocket" usage, none saying that upgrades to TLS would work. So the overall answer is that it's risky to rely on this in a production application.

Server support seems better; Apache has had "Upgrade: TLS" support since 2.1.

Comment: Chromium does not support "Upgrade: TLS", see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4527

Answer (score 0):

I would rather like to have it all in http, but the current situation leans more to Server Name Indication, as its widely supported. Its also hard to indicate that you want the client to upgrade using the url. So, if the goal is virtual hosting, one way to do this is TLS "server name indication".  See RFC 3546  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3546.txt or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Comment: My case deals with a custom program that implements an HTTP server.  I decided to simply redirect to HTTPS if HTTPS is enabled.  The "server name indication" feature really has nothing to do with what I was originally trying to accomplish nor does it have anything to do really with the HTTP upgrade mechanism.